# Can text editors like gedit access/edit remote files via fish?

Tags: linux, gedit, kdevelop, text-editor

Currently I'm using KDevelop for development in a remote server (far far away) via the Fish protocol (Files transferred over Shell protocol). However KDevelop is quite foreign for me (plus I'm not development KDE stuff) and I'd like to use gedit for development (customization!).

Does gedit work with FISH -and if so how do I do that? 
If not, what other customizable text editors that supports caching of remote files that I can use?

FYI: I've tried SSHFS method, but because of the network latency (MY <-> HK <-> US) using fish is the better option.

Comment: KDevelop is toolkit agnostic, you can develop anything with it - it's not limited to "KDE stuff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. gedit uses gvfs/gio, which supports SSH as one of its transport protocols.

Comment: So, it does not support fish? are there other application that supports fish/caching of remote files?

Comment: fish is KDE specific, but just a wrapper around sftp. gvfs/gio should come with an alternative to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rclone mount` if/then FISH backend is [ready](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/7301). Also KDE's kio is a [possible](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kio-extras/kioslave5/fish/index.html) option.